# Magento2 : Custom product attribute not filtering results in layered navigation

Tags: magento2

I have a custom product attribute name 'gg_availability' on my Magento 2 web store.

I've set it to appear in the layered navigation filter on the product list page. Any by I've set, I mean it was set and put into production months before I took on my role.

[image]
Selecting it adds the proper URL parameters and sets the left-hand filter appropriately. But, no results have been filtered out.

See below:

[image]
[image]

Any idea why? Is this a bug? Not a single preorder available item got filtered in *or* out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

EDIT: Caches have been cleared, the attribute scope is global, the indexers have been reindexed, and all products have this attribute set.

Comment: Not just "Filterable" will do the trick, you need to assign values for this attribute to the products which are in collection.

Comment: That's the unfortunate thing. All products have a value for that attribute.

Comment: Have you tried reindexing?

Comment: Set your attribute scope to global. Clear cache and see if it works.

Comment: The index and cache have been cleared numerous times, and unfortunately the product attribute has been global since its inception.

Comment: What is the Attribute Type?

Comment: The attribute type is an int